# How to parse output of TF command on the fly

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to perform a conditional check-in using TF command (shown below),

```
tf checkin /force /comment:"Some comment" /noprompt /override:"Check-in"
```

However problem is when my files are not changed, then the above command throws error (makes sense!). So I am looking to run some sort of conditional check using *folderdiff* command and parse the output before attempting to check-in.

```
tf folderdiff $/project/code d:/mycode /recursive /noprompt
```

This command throws up something like below,

#### Summary: 2 folders, 19 files, 0 source, 0 target, 0 different, 0 with errors

Question is - how do I parse this on the fly (to check if any file is different) and move to check-in them?

Comment: You could try to user powershell to get the output. It is easier to manipulate the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

> The output displayed in the Command Prompt window lists all the files
>   in the folders in the following five sections:
>
> - Items that exist only in the server folder.
> - Items that exist only in the local folder.
> - Items that have different contents.
> - Items that have identical contents (you must specify the same    argument with the /view option).
> - Summary.

If there is difference between files, you could see it under `Show Items That Have Different Contents` section.

[image]

Your example "Summary: 2 folders, 19 files, 0 source, 0 target, 0 different, 0 with errors" means there is no difference between the server and local folder.

Comment: Correct - so I would like to parse the o/p say '0 different' and then skip the next step. If there are files changed, then we would probably get something like your screenshot and execute the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it below way.
Firstly, I have used the standard *folderdiff* command and redirected the output to a separate text file.
Then I created a powershell script which then looks for a pattern in the text file and (if pattern is found) then sets a flag (defined a custom variable called MyVar in TFS),

```
$data= (Get-Content -Path $someFilePath | where-Object {$_ -like '*Your string pattern....*'})

if (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($data)))
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVar]True"      
    Write-Verbose "No files modified, so no check-in."
}
```

Finally, use this variable (MyVar) to create a conditional step for running TF checkin command.